# LogMessage not defined

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I try to compile my vba code (Access 2013) I get a popup saying sub or function not defined, it then proceeds to highlight `LogMessage`.

The entire code looks like:

```
Public Function test_List_Queries_by_Prefix()
    LogMessage List_Queries_by_Prefix("", True, False)
End Function
```

How can I stop this error from occurring?

Comment: Do you have a custom procedure named `LogMessage`?  Access VBA doesn't provide `LogMessage`.

Comment: Turns out it was a module I had imported and the guy had not defined his own function. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogMessage` is not a built-in Access sub or function. You'll need to provide that definition in a place that your function can reach it. Does this call work in a different database? Try searching that project for LogMessage.